# Google Cloud DNS type A not working

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I've added my nameservers to my registrar:

```
NS-CLOUD-E1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
NS-CLOUD-E2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
NS-CLOUD-E3.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
NS-CLOUD-E4.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM 
Updated 1/12/2016
```

Updated Google Cloud DNS:

```
DNS Name          Type  TTL     Data
dvotedfan.com.      A   300    130.211.8.93
www.dvotedfan.com.  A   300    130.211.8.93
dvotedfan.com.      NS   60    ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
                               ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
                               ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com.
                               ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.
```

Waited one day then:

I've check DNS and it has been resolved:
http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=dnsrec&host=dvotedfan.com

But if I ping the domain I get an error (Unknown error: 1214):
http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=ping&host=dvotedfan.com

I can access via my IP (Load balancer) 130.211.8.93 but not from domain name (dvotedfan.com)

Answer (score 1):

It could be network-tools.com is having some problems. It looks like it works to me.

```
stephen@stackoverflow:~$ ping -c 5 dvotedfan.com
PING dvotedfan.com (130.211.8.93) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.8.211.130.bc.googleusercontent.com (130.211.8.93): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=1.61 ms
64 bytes from 93.8.211.130.bc.googleusercontent.com (130.211.8.93): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=1.61 ms
64 bytes from 93.8.211.130.bc.googleusercontent.com (130.211.8.93): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=1.64 ms
64 bytes from 93.8.211.130.bc.googleusercontent.com (130.211.8.93): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=1.65 ms
64 bytes from 93.8.211.130.bc.googleusercontent.com (130.211.8.93): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=1.81 ms

--- dvotedfan.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.612/1.668/1.814/0.083 ms
```

Comment: Yes I've notice it works now. I've changed www.dvotedfan.com. to CNAME it started to work.